# Is it possible to host a static site using Amazon S3 and still have email via MX records?

Tags: domain-name-system

I am trying to host my private site using Amazon S3.  I would like the site to be setup at the root, or at the minimum setup at WWW.  S3 requires that you create an alias using a CNAME record.  However, when I setup a CNAME for WWW, the MX records no longer work.  I have read that this is per spec.  As I am not overly familiar with DNS, I feel like I could be missing something here.  So, my question is:  is it possible to host a static site using Amazon S3 at the root and still have email through Google Apps using MX records?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CNAME on `www.yourdomain.com` pointing to S3 should not interfere with MX records configured on `yourdomain.com`.  However, a CNAME configured on `yourdomain.com` would definitely prevent MX entries from working correctly.

To keep both email and the S3 CNAMEs, you're probably stuck with just CNAME'ing www and not the root.

The MX entries should be working if you don't have a CNAME on the root -- make sure you give it plenty of time for the entries to drop out of DNS resolvers' cache.

Comment: Thanks, I have a feeling I was doing something wrong. I still want someone to that types in http://yourdomain.com to go to http://www.yourdomain.com, but perhaps that needs to be done via .htaccess.

Comment: Definitely preferable, just can't work through a CNAME.  Couple options: 1) to use A records to point to the S3 addresses, but this would mean that your A records would need to change when Amazon's do. 2) point your root's A records at a web server that will redirect to www.  Some DNS providers offer this without needing to point it to your own server.